# Importing Python libraries with hyphen in the name

Tags: python, python-import, pypi, python-packaging

I create a Python library. It requires a Git repository and a name. I name it `my-library` and also inside the package folder `my-package`.

How should I:

1. install library `my-library` after I upload it to PyPI?
2. import the package `my-package` after I install the library?

Comment: You cannot import "my-package", it's `SyntaxError`. Rename it to `my_package` for importing.

Comment: To complement what @phd said: you can keep the project's name with an hyphen `my-package` (and it will be canonicalized in some cases, but nothing you have to do, this should be smooth and hands free), but you definitely have to rename the actual importable packages and modules so that they have valid Python names, meaning no hyphens `-` (among other things), and yes recommendation would be `my_package` with the underscore `_`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can name and install it from PyPi as "my-package" but you have to import it as "my_package"